# How to alert when part of text is highlighted in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How to alert when part of text is highlighted in tinymce editor?
Something like this

```
    $('textarea').select(function(){
      alert('123');
    });
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in a way that better illustrates the problem? Include what you have tried so far.

Comment: I trying show message for user when he do selects text in tinyMCE editor.
But event select([link](https://api.jquery.com/select/)) don't work in textarea with tinymce class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/RvCw4/4/) using the [onMouseUp event](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onMouseUp) to show [the currently selected content](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.getContent) (if non-empty)

Javascript:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options 
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "second",

    // Skin options
    skin: "o2k7",
    skin_variant: "silver",

    setup: function (ed) {
        // on mouse uo get selected text
        ed.onMouseUp.add(function (ed, e) {
            var highlighted = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
            if (highlighted) alert(highlighted);
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" id="second"></textarea>
```